# rcharts scatterplot with smooth curve

Tags: r, scatter-plot, rcharts

Is it possible to plot a scatterplot with a smooth curve and confidence interval using rcharts?

I can do it with ggvis or ggplot2 but I think rcharts graphics look better in general.

This is an example with ggvis

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_model_predictions(model = "lm", se = TRUE)
```

and this with ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
c + stat_smooth() + geom_point()
```

Thanks!

Comment: what library do you like best?  I am working on adding layer functionality to rCharts + dimple.

Comment: rcharts>ggplot2>ggvis. But that could rapidly change. I'm more familiar with ggplot2 and I have barely use the others. When I'm able to create a graph with rcharts i love the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Loess](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/scatter.smooth.html)?

Description

Plot and add a smooth curve computed by loess to a scatter plot.

Usage

```
scatter.smooth(x, y = NULL, span = 2/3, degree = 1,
    family = c("symmetric", "gaussian"),
    xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,
    ylim = range(y, pred$y, na.rm = TRUE),
    evaluation = 50, ..., lpars = list())

loess.smooth(x, y, span = 2/3, degree = 1,
    family = c("symmetric", "gaussian"), evaluation = 50, ...)
```

there is an example of such a chart [here](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Statistics/loess.htm)

[image: loess]

in rcharts you can use [J4L](http://www.java4less.com/chartsruby/userguide/linechart.htm#2)

Cubic curves: the points you provide will be contained in the curve.

SERIE_TYPE_1=CURVE  Use cubic natural curves

[image: j4l]